# Group_concat on IF Select MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mariadb-10.3, group-concatenation

I have a query as below:

```
SELECT o.order_id,
       c.customer_name,
       Group_concat(p.product_name, ' x', p.product_quantity ORDER BY
       receipt_order ASC
       SEPARATOR
       '<br>') AS items,
       order_status,
       o.delivery_collection,
       o.order_total,
       o.payment_method,
       o.discount_value,
       o.order_time,
       o.order_note,
       IF(o.delivery_collection = 'delivery', (SELECT
       Group_concat(address_1, address_2, postcode SEPARATOR '<br>') AS delAdd
                                               FROM   address a
                                               WHERE
       c.customer_id = a.customer_id
       AND c.customer_type =
           a.customer_type), NULL)
FROM   orders o,
       order_products p,
       customer c
WHERE  c.customer_id = o.customer_id
       AND c.customer_type = o.customer_type
       AND o.order_id = p.order_id
       AND order_time > Now() - INTERVAL 72 hour
GROUP  BY p.order_id
ORDER  BY order_status DESC,
          o.order_id DESC
```

The problem I have is that the `Group_Concat()` inside the `IF` concatenates but it doesn't include the separator and is not called `delAdd`.

I have also tried `CONCAT_WS` and `CONCAT` but all are giving the same results.

I am using MySQL 5.6.43 on 10.3.18-MariaDB server.

Answer (score 2):

To alias the expression computed inside a Correlated Subquery, you will need to specify it outside the complete subquery. In this case, it will be outside the `If(..)` block:

```
SELECT o.order_id,
       c.customer_name,
       Group_concat(p.product_name, ' x', p.product_quantity ORDER BY
       receipt_order ASC
       SEPARATOR
       '<br>') AS items,
       order_status,
       o.delivery_collection,
       o.order_total,
       o.payment_method,
       o.discount_value,
       o.order_time,
       o.order_note,
       IF(o.delivery_collection = 'delivery', 
          (SELECT Group_concat(address_1, 
                               address_2, 
                               postcode SEPARATOR '<br>') -- no need of aliasing here
           FROM   address a
           WHERE c.customer_id = a.customer_id
                 AND c.customer_type = a.customer_type), 
          NULL) AS delAdd  -- Aliasing needed here
FROM   orders o,
       order_products p,
       customer c
WHERE  c.customer_id = o.customer_id
       AND c.customer_type = o.customer_type
       AND o.order_id = p.order_id
       AND order_time > Now() - INTERVAL 72 hour
GROUP  BY p.order_id
ORDER  BY order_status DESC,
          o.order_id DESC
```

Comment: Great the alias works however the separator isn't showing, any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: @AbuNooh separator may be rendering as a line break due to HTML. Try to print it out as a character stream.

Comment: No it doesn't work, the first one seems to work fine.

Comment: @AbuNooh can you set up a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ with some small sample data to play with.

Comment: After playing about with it for a while, I have directly concatenated by placing `'<br>'` in between the field names.